# How do you create an Azure database from the pre-canned SQL script in Management Studio 2016?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've logged into my Azure account in SSMS 2016 and I want to create a Database named **Foobar** (I also want that DB to appear in the new Azure portal).  If I right click **Databases**  and select *New Database..." it presents to me a script.

```
--Comments from script removed

CREATE DATABASE <Database_Name, sysname, Database_Name> COLLATE <collation_Name, sysname, SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS> 
    (
      EDITION = '<EDITION, , Standard>',
      SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='<SERVICE_OBJECTIVE,,S0>',
      MAXSIZE = <MAX_SIZE,,1024 GB>
    )

GO
```

How would I modify that for **Foobar** and Tier **S0**?  I'm not sure what to do about **sysname** and other parameters in this script.  I've done a simple `Create database Foobar` which DOES create a database, but it is not appearing iuin the Azure console.

Answer (score 2):

I connected to my server and ran the following query against the master db

```
CREATE DATABASE [Foobar] 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    (
      EDITION = 'Standard',
      SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='S0',
      MAXSIZE = 250 GB
    )

   GO
```

And it created a database 'Foobar' of Tier 'S0' on my database.

Reference the [CREATE DATABASE command documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more details on the command.

**EDIT**: You may want to pay special attention to the Max_Size limits if you choose to include them in your create statement- going beyond the allowed Max_Size for your service objective will throw an error. (1024 GB, from your original code, would cause this problem at 'S0')